# Android Retrofit Get Data From JSON Response

Tags: android, json, retrofit

With my app I have the following JSON Response

```
{
    "status_code": 1000,
    "data": [
        "6b456880-629a-11e9-94e5-15f45eea94be",
        1101
    ],
    "message": "Verified"
}
```

Im using Retrofit and my response object is

```
public class basicRes {


    @SerializedName("status_code")
    int status_code;
    @SerializedName("data")
    userInfo data;
    @SerializedName("message")
    String message;

    public int getStatus_code() {
        return status_code;
    }

    public userInfo getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public class userInfo{
        String user_id;
        int province;

        public String getUser_id() {
            return user_id;
        }

        public int getProvince() {
            return province;
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error

**Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 29 path $.data**

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the JSON response is returning array for the `data` key, whereas the model type being used for `data` is object.

The response should be in format

```
{
    "status_code": 1000,
    "data": {
        "user_id": "6b456880-629a-11e9-94e5-15f45eea94be",
        "province": 1101
    },
    "message": "Verified"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your userInfo should be arraylist such as below:

public class basicRes {

```
@SerializedName("status_code")
int status_code;
@SerializedName("data")
Arraylist<userInfo> data = new Arraylist<userInfo>();
@SerializedName("message")
String message;

public int getStatus_code() {
    return status_code;
}

public Arraylist<userInfo> getData() {
    return data;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public class userInfo{
    String user_id;
    int province;

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public int getProvince() {
        return province;
    }
}
```